# How to install cassandra nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-ec2, cassandra, installation

I have a linux ec2 instance on amazon and have installed cassandra. I then installed nodejs and used

```
npm install node-cassandra-cql
```

to install the cassandra part of nodejs. I have tried out the basic scripts that were given:

```
//Creating a new connection pool to multiple hosts.
var cql = require('node-cassandra-cql');
var client = new cql.Client({hosts: ['host1', 'host2'], keyspace: 'keyspace1'});
client.execute('SELECT key, email, last_name FROM user_profiles WHERE key=?', ['jbay'],
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log('execute failed');
    else console.log('got user profile with email ' + result.rows[0].email);
  }
);
```

The problem is I get an error on the first line saying that the require is not defined. My server says everything is installed, is there some preference that could be catching me up?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error stating the `require` is not defined, perhaps you're not running this using the `node` binary?  I was able to execute the code doing the following:

From the root of my project, I executed:

```
$ npm install node-cassandra-cql
```

I created a file, `index.js` in the root of my project, and added the cassandra code you pasted above to the file.  I then executed (from that same directory):

```
$ node index.js
```

Comment: Yah all of that works fine for me, I can run files from my root directory. I installed a LAMP server though and store my files under /var/www/html/. I am running a .php file and call a javascript script with the code above in it. I have an iOS app am trying to connect to the server and run my php script to transfer data to my app. Is this the best way to access my cassandra database or how exactly would you transfer data from your server to the web or an app?

Comment: If you're going to use Node to access your database, I would recommend using Node to transfer the data over HTTP to your mobile app.  There are a lot of way to accomplish this, [Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a very common framework used to build APIs.  You could then wrap the logic you have above in an API and hit it from the remote mobile app.